# ElementNotVisibleException, is there a solution with Selenium?

Tags: python, html, symfony, selenium

I am having a strange error on my website testing today :

```
ElementNotVisibleException: Message: Element is not currently visible and so may not be interacted with
```

I want to test something really really simple with selenium, just to test if, when I click on my logo, i am redirected to the good landing page. 
I did this very simple code :

```
@classmethod
def setUp(self):
    self.driver = webdriver.Firefox()
    self.driver.get('http://localhost')


def test_navigation_to_home_page(self):

    # Click on the logo and check landing page
    self.driver.find_element_by_xpath("/html/body/header/div[2]/div/div/div//a").click()
    self.assertEqual(self.driver.current_url, 'http://localhost/')

@classmethod
def tearDown(self):
    self.driver.quit()
```

When I execute this code, I have the above error. I tried to wait page loading with a simple time.sleep, just see if it helps, but nothing change. 
You will probably see the "//a" in the xpath expression. That's not a mistake, it is because if I write /figure/a, I have a NoSuchElementException.
My code containing the logo I want to click on is the following :

pagelayout.html.twig :

```
{% block header %}
    {{ render(controller('MyBundle:PageLayout:getHeader',  {'active_page':activePage})) }}
{% endblock %}
```

header.html.twig :

```
<header id="header" class="header navbar-fixed-top">
{% include 'MyBundle:PageLayout:cookie_barre.html.twig'%}
{% include 'MyBundle:PageLayout:metabarre.html.twig'%}
<div class="header-bar container-fluid">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <figure class="header-logo header-item col-xs-8 col-sm-3"><a href="page-home">{{ ez_render_field(header, 'fs_header_logo', {'parameters':{'class': 'img-responsive'} } ) }}</a></figure>
                {{ render(controller('MyBundle:PageLayout:getMainMenu',  {'active_page':activePage, 'header':header})) }}
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

I did a lot of Selenium test on another application and didn't get any error of this kind. Is it because I am using ez platform as a render for my pictures ? Is there a way to fix this ? All the site works fine anyway, just need to automate some tests.

Thank you.

Comment: That XPATH is really generic and brittle. You are referencing an element from the HTML tag... can you be more specific in identifying the element? Is there not some class or ID or something you can also reference? Are you sure you are clicking the right one?

Comment: Ah... I saw the HTML you posted but didn't see the A tag you referenced at first... can you not use a CSS selector like "figure.header-logo > a"? I'm guessing that will be specific enough to get exactly the element you want. You could also dump the innerHTML to make sure you have the right one... assuming you can get past the ElementNotVisible. I'm assuming that waiting for the element to be visible won't help because it probably never becomes visible.. which makes me think something is slightly off with your XPATH.

Comment: Thank you for your response. 
I don't know if you see my edit but I can't use "figure" tag in my xpath because I get a NoSuchElementException when I do. I am going to try your solution with the CSS Selector because Selenium Firefox module returned me this action when I clicked on the logo : 

command clickAndWait target css=img.img-responsive

Going to try !

Comment: OK. I would suggest that you explore the HTML on the rendered page rather than the twigs. There may be something going on where all the elements are not rendered as you would expect. See if that helps. If not, grab some of the relevant HTML and update your question and maybe we can help further.

Comment: I finally manage to catch only the //a link and click on it. Seems to work, even if I still don't understand how /html/body/header/div[2]/div/div/div//a doesn't work and how only //a works.

Comment: Did you try the CSS selector I suggested above? It's best to be as specific as you can be. If that page changes and an A tag is added above the current one you are looking for, your automation may stop working.